# Show the limit $\lim_{\delta \to 0}\int_{\ln(1+\delta)}^{\delta} \frac{e^{-x}}{x}\,dx \to 0 $ in a proof of the Digamma function

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, limits, gamma-function, digamma-function

I want to show that
$$\lim_{\delta \to 0}\int_{\ln(1+\delta)}^{\delta} \frac{e^{-x}}{x}\,dx \to 0 \tag{1}$$

Intutitively I could take the limits before integration, then I would get

$$\int_{0}^{0} \frac{e^{-x}}{x}\,dx=0 $$ My question is whether this procedure is valid, or a more rigorous proof should be provided in he lines of

**Edit**: Being more careful in the calculations I could show the following estimate:

$$
\begin{align*}
\lim_{\delta \to 0}\int_{\ln(1+\delta)}^{\delta} \frac{e^{-x}}{x}\,dx & \leq \left| \lim_{\delta \to 0}\int_{\ln(1+\delta)}^{\delta} \frac{e^{-x}}{x}\,dx \right|\\
& \leq  \lim_{\delta \to 0}\int_{\ln(1+\delta)}^{\delta}\left| \frac{e^{-x}}{x}\right|\,dx \\
& \leq  \lim_{\delta \to 0}\int_{\ln(1+\delta)}^{\delta} \frac{dx}{x} \\
&=\lim_{\delta \to 0} \, \ln(x)\Big|_{\ln(1+\delta)}^{\delta}\\
&=-\lim_{\delta \to 0} \, \ln\left(\frac{\ln(1+\delta)}{\delta}\right)\\
&=- \ln\left(\lim_{\delta \to 0}\frac{\ln(1+\delta)}{\delta}\right) & \text{by continuity of log}\\
&=- \ln\left(\lim_{\delta \to 0}\frac{1}{\delta}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1} \delta^n}{n}\right)\\
&=- \ln\left(\lim_{\delta \to 0}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1} \delta^{n-1}}{n}\right)\\
&=-\ln(1)\\
&=0
\end{align*}
$$

**Motivation:**

The motivation behind this limit comes from a proof of an integral representation of the Digamma function.

If we define the Gamma function by the integral $(2)$ below and the digamma function by $\psi(z)=\frac{z}{dz}\ln\left(\Gamma(z) \right)$

$$\Gamma(z)= \int_0^\infty e^{-t}t^{z-1}\,dt \qquad \operatorname{Re}(z)>0\tag{2}$$

Differentiating $(2)$ w.r. to $z$ we obtain:

$$
\begin{align*}
\Gamma^\prime(z)&= \int_0^\infty e^{-t}t^{z-1} \ln(t)\,dt \qquad \operatorname{Re}(z)>0\\
&= \int_0^\infty e^{-t}t^{z-1} \left(\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x}-e^{-xt}}{x}\,dx \right)\,dt\\
&= \int_0^\infty \left(\int_0^\infty (e^{-x}-e^{-xt})e^{-t}t^{z-1}\,dt \right)\,\frac{dx}{x}\\
&= \int_0^\infty \left(e^{-x}\int_0^\infty e^{-t}t^{z-1}\,dt-\int_0^\infty e^{-t(1+x)}t^{z-1}\,dt \right)\,\frac{dx}{x}\\
&= \int_0^\infty \left(e^{-x}\Gamma(z)-\frac{1}{(1+x)^z}\int_0^\infty e^{-t}t^{z-1}\,dt \right)\,\frac{dx}{x}\\
&= \int_0^\infty \left(e^{-x}\Gamma(z)-\frac{1}{(1+x)^z}\Gamma(z)\right)\,\frac{dx}{x}\\
&=\Gamma(z) \int_0^\infty \left(e^{-x}-\frac{1}{(1+x)^z}\right)\,\frac{dx}{x}\\
\end{align*}
$$

Therefore we have

$$\psi(z)=\int_0^\infty \left(e^{-x}-\frac{1}{(1+x)^z}\right)\,\frac{dx}{x} \tag{3}$$

Than

$$
\begin{align*}
\psi(z)&= \lim_{\delta \to 0}\int_{\delta}^\infty \left(e^{-x}-\frac{1}{(1+x)^z}\right)\,\frac{dx}{x}\\
&= \lim_{\delta \to 0}\left[\int_{\delta}^\infty \frac{e^{-x}}{x}\,dx-\int_{\delta}^\infty \frac{1}{x(1+x)^z}\,dx\right]\\
&= \lim_{\delta \to 0}\left[\int_{\delta}^\infty \frac{e^{-x}}{x}\,dx-\int_{\ln(1+\delta)}^\infty \frac{e^{-xz}}{1-e^{-x}}\,dx\right] & (x+1 \to e^{x})\\
&= \lim_{\delta \to 0}\left[\int_{\ln(1+\delta)}^\infty \frac{e^{-x}}{x}\,dx-\int_{\ln(1+\delta)}^\infty \frac{e^{-xz}}{1-e^{-x}}\,dx+\int_{\delta}^{\ln(1+\delta)} \frac{e^{-x}}{x}\,dx\right] \\
&= \lim_{\delta \to 0}\left[\int_{\ln(1+\delta)}^\infty \frac{e^{-x}}{x}- \frac{e^{-xz}}{1-e^{-x}}\,dx-\int_{\ln(1+\delta)}^{\delta} \frac{e^{-x}}{x}\,dx\right] \\
&=\int_{0}^\infty \frac{e^{-x}}{x}- \frac{e^{-xz}}{1-e^{-x}}\,dx, \qquad \operatorname{Re}(z)>0
\end{align*}
$$

Provided $(1)$ holds.

Comment: If your goal is to show the limit and even get the asymptotics, you could do is faster and get as a result $\frac{\delta }{2}-\frac{17 }{24}\delta ^2+O\left(\delta ^3\right)$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici How did you get the expansion?  Expanding the exponential in Maclaurin series? Or integrating by parts repeatedly? Actually the integrand is  the same as the exponential integral function.

Comment: If you know that $\text{Ei}(-x)=(\log (x)+\gamma )-x+\frac{x^2}{4}-\frac{x^3}{18}+O\left(x^4\right)$ compose the Taylor series

Comment: Apply mean value theorem for integrals.

Answer (score 2):

For $\delta\in(0,1)$, we have that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\ln(1+\delta) & = & \delta-\frac{\delta^{2}}{2}+\frac{\delta^{3}}{3}-\frac{\delta^{4}}{4}+\ldots\\
 & \geq & \delta-\frac{\delta^{2}}{2}+\frac{\delta^{3}}{3}
\end{eqnarray*}
because $-\frac{\delta^{4}}{4}+\frac{\delta^{5}}{5}-\ldots<0$. Since
the integrand $x\mapsto\frac{e^{-x}}{x}$ is positive and $\delta-\frac{\delta^{2}}{2}+\frac{\delta^{3}}{3}\leq\ln(1+\delta)\leq\delta$,
we have that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{\ln(1+\delta)}^{\delta}\frac{e^{-x}}{x}dx & \leq & \int_{\delta-\frac{\delta^{2}}{2}+\frac{\delta^{3}}{3}}^{\delta}\frac{e^{-x}}{x}dx\\
 & \leq & \int_{\delta-\frac{\delta^{2}}{2}+\frac{\delta^{3}}{3}}^{\delta}\frac{dx}{\delta-\frac{\delta^{2}}{2}+\frac{\delta^{3}}{3}}\\
 & = & \frac{1}{\delta-\frac{\delta^{2}}{2}+\frac{\delta^{3}}{3}}\cdot\left(\frac{\delta^{2}}{2}-\frac{\delta^{3}}{3}\right)\\
 & \rightarrow & 0
\end{eqnarray*}
as $\delta\rightarrow0^{+}$. On the other hand, clearly $\int_{\ln(1+\delta)}^{\delta}\frac{e^{-x}}{x}dx\geq0$.
By sandwich rule, we conclude that $\lim_{\delta\rightarrow0+}\int_{\ln(1+\delta)}^{\delta}\frac{e^{-x}}{x}dx=0$.

Comment: If you are asking two-sided limit, the case that $\delta\rightarrow 0^-$ can be handled similarly and is left to you.